# is it possible to access Paypal on Parse cloud code

Tags: android, paypal, parse-platform

since i try to verify Paypal payment on cloud code

below is my code in cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("verify", function(request, response) {

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment',
    body: {
        'xx'
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer xx'
    },
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        response.success("success");
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
        response.success(httpResponse.text);
    }
});
});
```

response is

> You don't have permission to access
>   "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment" on this server.

am i doing something wrong or i can't do in this way?

if i don't have permission to access Paypal via Parse.com and i don't have my own Server

how do i verify payment?

what is the problem if i will verify payment on mobile device?

Comment: can you say how did you solve it? I'm stuck on creating an access_token from cloud code